# Several count aggregation output in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

So I have a collection like this:

```
{
 'region': '1',
 'status': 'a',
 'sum': 100
}
{
 'region': '1',
 'status': 'b',
 'sum': 80
}
{
 'region': '2',
 'status': 'a',
 'sum': 20
}
{
 'region': '2',
 'status': 'a',
 'sum': 30
}
```

And the desired result must be like this:

```
[
  {
    'region': '1',
    'status_a': 1,
    'status_b': 1,
    'sum': 180
  },
  {
    'region': '2',
    'status_a': 2,
    'sum': 50
  }
]
```

Any suggestions? The number of regions as well as the number of statuses can vary and I need to always output the sum for the entire `region` despite statuses

P.S if you wanna be super specific with your answer, then region and status fields are ObjectId's, thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$group` by both `region` and `status` and count `status` and sum
- `$group` by only `region` and `$concat` `status_` and its value after converting object id to string using `$toString`
- construct the array of `status` and `statusCount` in key-value format
- `$arrayToObject` convert above converted array to object
- `$mergeObjects` to merge required fields and `status` object
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merged document in root

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { region: "$region", status: "$status" },
      statusCount: { $sum: 1 },
      sum: { $sum: "$sum" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.region",
      status: {
        $push: {
          k: { $concat: ["status_", { $toString: "$_id.status" }] },
          v: "$statusCount"
        }
      },
      sum: { $sum: "$sum" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          { $arrayToObject: "$status" },
          {
            resion: "$_id",
            sum: "$sum"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6Ulymaj7_ak)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, for some odd reason it puts region ObjectId in status_*, like this

{ region: ObjectId("5fb2a325a29bb768f7c5c98e"),
    sum: 47006,
    status_5fb37d9e87b38ebe6c815647: ObjectId("5fb2a325a29bb768f7c5c98e"),
    status_5fb37dd187b38ebe6c815649: ObjectId("5fb2a325a29bb768f7c5c98e") }

Comment: you said in your question => *region and status fields are ObjectId's,* so and for status_a means concat status value right?

Comment: No, I just now realised i was quite unclear in question, sorry for that

I need count of all statuses within given region, more like that

Like if region "A" i have 2 documents with status 'B' and 3 documents with status 'C' the result must be {region: A, status_B: 2, status_C: 3}

Comment: see update playground link, i have just added your payload. its exact as per your expected result.

Comment: Yes! Exactly as I want, thank you very much, now I need to figure out how to fetch data based on date (because this aggregation must be daily for 00:00 to 23:59), but this is for another question